# Converting Windows installation into HP/dELL OEM version

Tags: operating-systems, dell-inspiron, clone

Often I will upgrade clients PCs to some Dell/HP machine, where the licence key is inbuilt into the OS and hardware so you will not have a licence key on the machine.

Often we used to clone users HD and just change the drivers to work with the new machine, but if we do this with these Dell/HP machines the licence key will not work.
Is there anyway to clone the HD from the old machine and still have the licence key work?

Comment: " Is there anyway to clone the HD from the old machine and still have the licence key work?" - SysPrep the image before you apply it to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: AT Ramhound..  you should state that that has nothing to do with dell/hp and  the dell/hp version of windows that has its own license number. And you should state if what you suggest  has anything to do with license details, or if it's just to do with dissimilar hardware.

Comment: -1 you wrote "the licence key is inbuilt into the OS and hardware so you will not have a licence key on the machine." <-- that makes no sense. Certainly Dell and perhaps HP too, have their own vesrions of windows that have their own license key, and the key is stamped on the machine on a label, and probably accessible with the same software that reveals a key of a non-dell regular windows..